# Disable a Custom Taxonomies default save mechanism

Tags: custom-taxonomy, automation

I have a custom taxonomy X.

I've specified that the UI should be shown (for debugging purposes), however the UI is now interfering with my automation. I have code that automatically mirrors terms into this taxonomy, duplicating it. Taxonomy X is effectively a copy of Taxonomy Y or a subset. This code is working almost perfectly, except that my assignment code is doing its work which is then undone by the WordPress UI code setting the terms for the post from the metabox.

So how do I make the metabox showing Taxonomy X terms read only? AKA keep the metabox, but remove any save/edit/delete hooks attached to it?

***edit:** for reference, if `show_ui` is set to false in the registration of the taxonomy, and the UI for that tax is hidden, then everything works as expected. ( which itself is to be expected)*

Comment: Do you need the metabox?

Comment: No but if things it would be useful for development purposes

Comment: Then try removeing just the metabox : `remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-custom_taxonomy_id', 'post', 'side' );`

Comment: But then how will I view the terms? I want the UI so I can see what's happening in my hidden taxonomy when I'm doing dev work, I just don't want WordPress to interfere with my own automation by attempting to set the object terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Bainternet suggested - `remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-custom_taxonomy_id', 'post', 'side' );` to remove the default Metabox. If you want to still *see* the terms. Then re-register the metabox with your own custom callback.

This callback function can then mimic the function used to display the default metabox - but simply omitting any input forms /checkboxes which send any data.

The function you'll want to mimic is:

- For non-hierarchical taxonomies: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L265
- For hierarchical taxonomies: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L307

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, and I learnt something new, thankyou =)